# Gremlin query to list out all the edges by the same label

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, tinkerpop

I tried different queries matching my request but unable to find it. Sorry of this is a duplicate.
I have two vertices `Vertex1` and `Vertex2`. There is an edge connecting from `Vertex1` to `Vertex2`  with label `relation` properties `{name: "Test1"}`. Similarly there is one more edge connecting from `Vertex1` to `Vertex2` with the same label as `relation` but properties as `{name: "Test2"}`. The attached picture shows the vertices and its relation.
[image]

How to list all the relations?

Query1: `g.V('Vertex1').outE().hasLabel('relation')` => List only the first relation i.e. the relation with properties {name: "Test1"}.

Query2: `g.V('Vertex1').outE().as("c").select("c").by(valueMap()).toList()` => List out all the relations including the edge with label "relation".

If I tweak little bit to include the label name to query as
`g.V('Vertex1').outE('relation').as("c").select("c").by(valueMap()).toList()` => then again getting only the first edge.
I am trying to get just the properties of the edge with label "relation" and its properties,like

```
{id=Edge1-ID1, label=relation, name=Test1}

{id=Edge1-ID2, label=relation, name=Test2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong but your first attempt is essentially the right one given Gremlin syntax:

```
gremlin> g.addV().property(id,'Vertex1').as('v1').
......1>   addV().property(id,'Vertex2').as('v2').
......2>   addE('relation').from('v1').to('v2').property('name','Test1').
......3>   addE('relation').from('v1').to('v2').property('name','Test2').iterate()
gremlin> g.V('Vertex1').outE('relation')
==>e[0][Vertex1-relation->Vertex2]
==>e[1][Vertex1-relation->Vertex2]
gremlin> g.V('Vertex1').outE('relation').values('name')
==>Test1
==>Test2
```

My only thought here is that perhaps you aren't fully [iterating your traversal](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration)? You did a `toList()` in your other examples, but not the first.

Comment: It is strange, I tried the Query 1 yesterday it did not work. Today after your post, I pulled it from the history and rerun it, it works now.

Comment: To add a context, I am using Java to update the edges and using gremlin console to query it. I need to close the existing gremlin session and open a new one, to get the updated query result.